# "Where is the framework?" error in Play! framework

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, console, playframework

I am new to using the Play! framework and was following the tutorial on their site and I got the following error in the console while trying to run the program.

```
~
~ play! 1.1, http://www.playframework.org
~
~ Ctrl+C to stop
~ 
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
Exception in thread "main" play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Where is the framework ?
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:193)
    at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:131)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:150)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:87)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:66)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:71)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1029)
    at play.Play.init(Play.java:178)
    ... 1 more
```

Could someone please figure out what the problem is and solution to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the play.jar file is corrupted (look at the root exception). Try to download it again, or run 'ant'.

**EDIT:**
Rename your Play! directory as Play. The ! symbol is used internally in jar URL pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I would say... It doesn't find the framework.

Are you sure everything is well installed?

Do you have some env variables to set?

Some configuration files to set?

Cheers,

Comment: I extracted the downloaded zip file.
Set the environment variables to the directory using

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Play\!/play-1.1
export PATH

Also edited the .bashrc file to make the changes to path permanent.

Comment: So rename your Play! directory as Play. The ! symbol is used internally in jar URL pattern.

Comment: @Guillaume: It worked. Thanks. (Could you please post this comment as a different answer so that I can select it as the correct one.)